# Localhost and Ionic View

Tags: angularjs, wcf, rest, ionic-framework

I am testing in my browser using Ionic Serve and I am also connecting to a RESTful WCF Service running on a Localhost. I want to be able to connect to that service using the Ionic View App. Is it possible to connect to a local host with an external device like using Ionic view app on my device or do I need to host my service differently?

Comment: You mean to say you want to run application on your mobile device and serve with server running on your localhost ?

Comment: Basically Yes. @mudasserajaz

Answer (score 2):

1. computer and device on same network
2. goto computer command prompt and run this command **ipconfig**
   you will get internet ip address like e.g:**192.168.0.102**
3. now move to your device set **http:// 192.168.0.102:yourapilink?parameters=1**
   please like if answer really helpfull

Comment: Do mean that my address will look like this: http://192.168.1.113/Service1.svc/GetAllComp or like:http://192.168.1.113:Service1.svc/GetAllComp @owaisali

Comment: first part was ip addres http://192.168.1.113
then port set which one you given IIS :70
finally your service address look like http://192.168.1.113:70/Service1.svc/GetAllComp

Comment: I am not hosting in IIS I am running is through Visual Studio debug @owaisali

Comment: you must have to configure IIS then access service URL

Comment: So there is no way to connect to a service running on localhost without IIS? @owaisali

Answer (score 0):

There are tools available, but most easy way will be this:

1. Make sure both computer and mobile are on same network.
2. Run server on localhost, and in client side code replace `localhost` with the IP address of your system where you are making api calls. For example `localhost/api/login` with `192.168.1.102/api/login`.

Now your mobile will be getting response from server running on your system.

Comment: I am getting an error : `403 Forbidden` when typing it in my browser.. what ip would I use my pc or the network? @mudasserajaz

Comment: For confirmation, when you enter localhost or your IP address on your computer browser , they both give same response.At network level mobile device recognize your computer(where server is running) from it's IP.

Comment: this is weird when using localhost it works but using ip it gives me error :    ` HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.`

Comment: http://localhost:15021/Service1.svc  -  http://192.168.1.113/Service1.svc?wsdl @mudasserajaz

Comment: Add port number  192.168.1.113:15021/Service1.svc , then check.

Comment: no it shows: `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.` now @mudasserajaz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87270/discussion-between-mudasser-ajaz-and-renaldo-geldenhuis).